# Queries stop working after idle

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, laravel

The website I'm developing relies on jQuery AJAX calls a lot.
It's built on Laravel.
When you click an item it triggers a jQuery function that makes an AJAX call to Laravel controller (shows a preloader, than on success finishes it).

It all works perfect, but when the website stays open in your browser without you doing anything in it for some hours all those clicks just show the preloader and the AJAX call never returns a success.

That's really hard to debug since I have to wait hours to test one solution.

I think that if the controller wasn't responding the AJAX would just fire a 404 (as it has happened before) so it must be the sql server failing to do the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u stay idle for sometime, the csrf token will expire and you will get error with status 419.

You may try to exclude that particular route from csrf protection:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: Awesome, what about the urls with get directives? Like ``partial/article/{id}/{type}``. What syntax should I use to include those in the ``$except`` array?

Comment: U may use  `'partial/*'`